# Innerclass belongs to the instance of the Outerclass then why it can be declared static and how we are able to make the instance of static class?

Tags: java, static, inner-classes

I am learning Java and a bit confused in the concept of Inner class being declared Static. As far as I have learned Declaring any member static means it is belongs to the class level and not the instance of the class and Inner Class is the instance of the Outer Class and we can instantiate it as many times as we want.

So, how we can declare it as Static? It contradicts the concept of static keyword. And By declaring the class static Shouldn't all the members of that class by default becomes static ? But it is not the case. Why?

```
  class Outerclass{
            static int a=10;
            static class Innerclass{
                          System.out.println(a);
            }
   }
```

Comment: Because class member can be static.

Comment: What it means is that the `Innerclass` is not associated to a specific instance of `Outerclass`.  No more, no less.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you have this:

```java
public class Outer {

    class InstanceInner {
    }

    static class StaticInner{
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Main main = new Main();

        Inner instanceInner = main.new Inner();

        Main.StaticInner staticInner = new Main.StaticInner();

    }

}
```

Now:

```java
InstanceInner instanceInner = main.new InstanceInner();
```

creates instance of the inner class, that is instance member of `Main` class; i.e. every instance of `InstanceInner` will be belonging to the particular instance of `Main`. Like other instance fields or methods.

This line, however:

```java
Main.StaticInner staticInner = new Main.StaticInner();
```

creates instance of the `StaticInner` class, that is static member of the `Main`; i.e. every instance of `StaticInner` will be a static member of `Main` class.

Bear in mind:

- a static nested class interacts with the instance members of its outer class (and other classes) just like any other top-level class;
- because an inner class is associated with an instance, it cannot define any static members itself;
- objects that are instances of an inner class exist within an instance of the outer class.